# How to redirect example.mydomain.com to folder.mydomain.com via DNS/.htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, hosting

Is it somehow possible to redirect `example.mydomain.com`, a subdomain which does not actually exist, to `folder.mydomain.com` using either `.htaccess` or `DNS`? How can this be achieved?

When I access `DNS` from the control panel and click on the `Web DNS` tab, I see `Personal web DNS settings`, under which I believe I can submit domains and their values. However, I am confused with the `type` (web alias, web forward, A, CNAME, TXT, SRV, AAAA...). Could someone help me?

If the `.htaccess` way is simpler, I would then prefer it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use `.htaccess` as the subdomain does not exist.

I assume, from the process you described, that you are using One.com hosting. If so, the following guide will be of help:

[Manage your DNS settings](http://www.one.com/en/support/guide/manage-your-dns-settings)

Essentially, a web forward DNS entry will work for you:

1. Click on the *Web DNS* tab.
2. In the hostname/domain column, enter the subdomain you would like to redirect.
3. Set the type to *web forward*
4. Set the *value* to where you would like to be redirected when visiting the subdomain.
5. Click the (+) sign to save your changes.

It will take up to 90 minutes for your changes to take effect.